# Bluemix Node-Red Error: request entity too large

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, node-red

I've been trying to send base64 data to my node-red in bluemix

however it states that my file the request entity is too large...

I've been searching....
Can bodyparser module handle this?
Or is there any solution easier that changing the code since I cannot download the starter code to manipulate as it redirects me to the homepage

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

You can customise the maximum size of request the body-parser middleware (and the other middleware used by node-red) handles by using the `apiMaxLength` setting in your `bluemix-settings.js` file. It defaults to `1mb`.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't find apiMaxLength variable in the settings.js

Comment: right - the default one doesn't contain it... and I realise we didn't add it to the main docs either... will get that fixed.

Comment: Can I add it by my own to my bluemix-settings via my jazz.hub?

Comment: and on what scope can i put that variable?

Comment: Yes, you can edit bluemix-settings via whatever means you want. You should add it as a property of the `settings` object in that file - somewhere around here: https://github.com/node-red/node-red-bluemix-starter/blob/master/bluemix-settings.js#L31

Comment: Hi I did change my code adding apiMaxLenght:'10MB', still not working

Comment: I had no luck either.